# How do I perform a command line install when the alternate cd boots to EFI and Grub2

Tags: installation, grub2

I have a Lenovo x120e, and when I boot the alternate CD I get a grub2 bootloader. How do I select a command line install from the Grub2 bootloader? Is there a switch, option, or flag I can pass to start the minimal install vs the full installer?

Answer (score 1):

You choose what packages to install in the text mode installer process, not from grub.  When you get to the task selection, simply uncheck the desktop option.

Answer (score 0):

Previously, there was a "cli" option in minimal CD. Perhaps this option still works. You should try it, if you have not done so already.